# OneToMany relationship doesn't update id of object added

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a one to many relationship between Advertisement and QuestionAnswers now when I add a questionAnswer object and persist it I see that an insert is made in QuestionAnswers but the object that I added does not change its id.

In advertisement.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "advertisement", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<QuestionAnswers> getQuestionAnswers() {
    return questionAnswers;
}
```

in questionanswer.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_id")
public Advertisement getAdvertisement() {
    return advertisement;
}
```

Testcase

```
public void testAddQA(){
    User user=userRepository.findByEmail("abc@gmail.com");
    Advertisement adv=new Advertisement();
    adv.setAdvertisementStatus(statusRepository.findByStatus("A"));
    adv.setMaximumPrice(new BigDecimal(12));
    adv.setDescription("blabla");
    adv.setAdvertiser(user);
    advertisementRepository.save(adv);

    QuestionAnswers ans=new QuestionAnswers();
    ans.setAdvertisement(adv);
    ans.setQuestion("blabla");
    ans.setQuestionDate(new Date());
    ans.setBidder(user);
    adv.addQuestions(ans);

    advertisementRepository.save(adv);
    assertNotNull(ans.getId());


}
```

Not sure what's happening

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware when persisting `@OneToMany` collection via a cascade insert (when new items are added to the collection) hibernate (if Hibernate is being used as JPA provider) actually creates a new instance of the `QuestionAnswers` class and substitutes the one you have added to the `Advertisement.questions` collection. This instance actually has an ID. You can confirm this by examining the `Advertisement.questions` collection via a debugger after the `advertisementRepository.save(adv);`. You should see the following picture

1. `QuestionAnswers` instance contained within the `Advertisement.questions` has an id generated and set on it
2. Your instance of the `QuestionAnswers` is actually a different instance then the one contained in `Advertisement.questions`
3. Make sure to examine the state only after `advertisementRepository.save(adv);` is executed

A possible alternative could be trying to locate the `QuestionAnswers` within `Advertisement.questions` collection after a save is completed (as long as you have a way to uniquely identify it using other fields).

Hope this helps.